# How to override configuration of child project, added as jar in Gradle?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

how can we override configuration of dependent child project in a Gradle project for example.
I have 2 Gradle project.

1. project 1 : this project has actual business logics.
2. project 2 : this project specified a flow of the execution with the help of spring boot.

now project 1 has dependency on project 2 as jar.

project 1 -> build.gradle -> project 2(as jar)

now as we can see project 2 only has flow, and all the business logic and structure is in project 1. so how can I pass details of project 1 to project 2.

like
configuration class,
base project (for component scan)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Circular dependencies between projects are not allowed in Gradle. If Project2 depends on Project1, then in Project1 _cannot_ depend on  Project2. (This is a simplification, it is actually possible with clever usage of [configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_configuration), an example of which is [Java test fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures)). You will have to split up your projects into shareable chunks.